# Magical fantasy book with red haired girl and a talking moving road

Tags: story-identification, novel

It's a book that I read in maybe 2019, it's a magical fantasy book. It's about a red haired girl who's moving and her dad has left her, furthermore she has magic powers.  One memorable thing from the book was that it involved a talking moving road somehow? Somewhere along the story she flies and there's a bird involved too.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: The op used the tag - "the-road" which is regarding the 2006 novel which I dont think is the answer, was that intentional or by mistake?

Comment: Pretty sure it was a mistake. I eliminated it the first time I was trying to edit the question (but got scooped by others).

Answer (score 2):

*[All the Colors of Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43319667-all-the-colors-of-magic)* by Valija Zinck

[image: Front cover of All the Colors of Magic]

> Penelope has always been different from other children. Her hair has been gray since she was born. It rains every year on her birthday. And she knows what her mother is going to say before the words even come out of her mouth. But one day, Penelope wakes up with sparkling red hair and her mother confesses the truth: Her father is not only still alive, he's a wizard! Penelope has inherited his powers, and must embark on a journey to find him.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2490378785) mentions the talking road:

> The story follows Penelope, a young girl with grey hair and a strange smell of smoke that follows her everywhere she goes. She lives with her mother and grandmother in a red and green 'dragon' house and all she knows about her father is that he died many years before.
> Her life is turned upside-down when she overhears a conversation between her mother and grandmother about a letter from her father, then her hair mysteriously turns bright red. It turns out that Penelope's father was no ordinary person and she seems to have inherited his ability to do magic. Yet, it's frustrating trying to learn magic on her own so Penelope sets out to find where these mysterious letters come from and get to the bottom of the mystery surrounding her father...

....

> I liked some of the quirky additions such as the talking road and the spiders with grand names. The translation read very smoothly and my only real wish was for more information about the system of magic and how it worked.

Found with a search for `site:goodreads.com girl "talking road"`

Comment: while editing the question I by mistake missed the "Talking moving " part of the road, the road moves too. So I request you to check if your answer is still relevant

Comment: @shanu: Not 100%, but https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3028080501 mentions the road being able to "speed her on her way", which suggests that it can also move itself. Otherwise, it seems an almost total match. Red hair, sudden powers, missing father that she's seeking, and talking road.